# Finding the actual RTMP Stream URL?

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, rtmp

Let me go with an example. This is the video embed code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>

<div id="container">Loading the player ...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
        flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",
        file: "bmw/250413/vod.flv",
        streamer:'rtmp://216.185.104.75/vod',
        autoplay:"true",
        icons:"true",
        skin:"glow.zip",
        controlbar:"over",
        height: 270,
        width: 480,
        image: "images/bmw1.jpg"
    });
</script>
```

And this is the actual page: `http://www.24framesdigital.com/bmw/webcast/250413/vod.html`

Now, what would be the URL of the RTMP stream? I've tried:

```
rtmp://www.24framesdigital.com/bmw/250413/vod.flv
rtmp://www.24framesdigital.com/bmw/webcast/250413/bmw/250413/vod.flv
rtmp://216.185.104.75/vod/bmw/250413/vod.flv
rtmp://216.185.104.75/bmw/250413/vod.flv
```

...among a few others. None work. I'm using curl to stream/download the video:

```
curl rtmp://.../vod.flv -o vod.flv
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```sh
curl -o vod.flv 'rtmp://216.185.104.75/vod playpath=bmw/250413/vod'
```

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 3341k    0 3341k    0     0  97954      0 --:--:--  0:00:34 --:--:--  261k
```

More info
[in the man](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/librtmp.3.html)

Comment: Also, just wanted to know why you edited out: `$ rtmpdump -r rtmp://216.185.104.75/vod -y bmw/250413/vod -o a.flv`? (If it's good, please keep it in the answer -- it's not available in the versions of this answer.)

Comment: Okay, one last thing. Why should the `playpath` or `-y` be `bmw/250413/vod` and NOT `bmw/250413/vod.flv` (which obviously, doesn't work) as seen in the code? How did you deduce that it should be that way?

Comment: @TheoneManis I used RtmpDumpHelper. This is a pain however because it is only for Windows, not sure of a Linux solution.

Comment: BTW for MS windows command prompt dont forget to use double quotes not single quotes around "rtmp://216.185.104.75/vod playpath=bmw/250413/vod".