# How to get video URL to download video from RTMP stream

Tags: flash, url, video, rtmp

I need to download video from flash web player that uses RTMP.

There is video: http://www.metropol.cz/widgets/show/7507/

At the page source is:

```
 var startPlay = false;

    var player = jwplayer("video-player").setup({
      file: "shows/prazsky_expres/140613_1005-PRAZSKY_EXPRES.mp4",
      streamer: "rtmp://91.103.163.202/vod",      provider: 'rtmp',      

              image: "http://www.metropol.cz/public/content-images/cz/shows_part/146155_b.jpg",
```

but how can I determine stream url? I tried a lof of possible combination - nothing happens.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16231611/1974494 do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rtmpdump -r rtmp://91.103.163.202/vod -a vod -y mp4:shows/prazsky_expres/140612_1005-PRAZSKY_EXPRES.mp4 -W http://www.metropol.cz/public/jwplayer/player.swf -p http://www.metropol.cz/porady/prazsky-expres/7489/  -o prazsky_vyber.flv
```